# Maintain collection view selected state after table view cell reloadData

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, uicollectionview, tableview

I have a collection view and some other data as part of a table view cell.
The collection view cells are selectable ensuring a single selection of an item.
The use case now is I need to make an API call that will refresh the cell's data. After the API is fetched, I reload the table view cell with:

```
tableView.reloadRows(at: [indexPath], with: .automatic)
```

The issue is reloading the table view also loses the collection view cell selected state.
Is there any way to **preserve the selected state** or **reload the cell without reloading the collection view**?

Anyone has ideas, please help.

Comment: The most efficient way is to add a `isSelected` property in your data model.

Answer (score 0):

The simplest option I can think of is to use UICollectionView with compositionalLayout instead of your tableView and save the selected item index.

Another option is to save the selected state of the collectionView objects in your tableView dataSource, i.e. let's say you have a list of items (of type A) building your tableView cells, one of them has a list of items (of type B) building the collectionView cells, when you select an item (of type B), update that item in the outer list (of items of type A)

When fetching new results, make sure to update the selected state from the current results before replacing.

Answer (score 0):

My idea is to use one variable. And every time you click cell, you update indexPath to the variable.

```swift
var clickCell: IndexPath?
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
  clickCell = indexPath // update value
}
```

and after reloading the table view add this code

```
if let index = clickCell {
  tableView.selectRow(at: index, animated: true, scrollPosition: .none)
}
```

Comment: Need to select the item of the collection view inside table view cell. I tried with collectionview.selectItem but did not work.

Comment: I created a variable that keeps the selected cell index of the collection view before loading the table view cell. And then used collectionview.selectItem at the index which was kept in the variable after cell reload. That didn't work.